# Can't see number of answers posted with current meta.superuser colour scheme

Tags: bug, status-completed

[image]

I mean look at it! n votes say how many answer(s) posted ?

Comment: That's because it's a subtle hint that there really are no answers at all.

Comment: Seriously, you thought you would get answers hear? haha

Comment: It looks as if this has been changed already - as if looks different/OK to me!? (Is that why it's tagged "status-completed"?)

Comment: @w3d: Yeah seems its been fixed now.